# How to generate html page with a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, video

How do I implement video keys on my website?
Like when I click a link, it generates an html page containing a specific type of content and gets deleted in certain amount of time.

I haven't done anything code yet.
My only solution is to hard code every html page not generating it.
I don't know how to make those like in YouTube where they can generate "watch?v=[key]" like that

thank you in advance :)

Comment: I want it to be like when I click a link, it generates an html file containing a specific embedded video.

Comment: You don't need to create an html file for each resource. Use url parameters to determine what to display in a template file for that type of content. That's how dynamic content typically works

Comment: I dont really know what you just said/

Comment: Urls can have `hash` or `search parameters` that you read with your code to determine what to display on that page. Do some research on how both of those work and how to parse them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window.open() open new window

```
const openWidow = ()=>{
    var win = window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gjnup-PuquQ", 'window name', config = 'height=500,width=500');
}
```

also can use window.close() close this window

reference [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)